# Проблема с разбором текстов, содержащих символы /, [, ], b

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Писал JS обработчик для форума и столкнулся с проблемой:
При раскладе:

```
"[b]проверка[/b]текст[b]тест[/b]".replace(/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/g, "<b>$1</b>")
```

Выходит: `"проверка[/b]текст[b]тест"`

При раскладе:

```
"[b]проверка[/b]текст[b]тест[/b]".replace(/\[b\]([^\\[\/b\\]]+)\[\/b\]/g, "<b>$1</b>")
```

Выходит: `проверкатексттест`

Проблема: тексты, содержащие символы `/ [ ] b` не парсятся

Как по-другому составить 2-е выражение, или что можно ещё сделать, чтобы выходило всё верно?
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"[b]проверка[/b]текст[b]тест[/b]".replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/g, "<b>$1</b>")
```

У вас в первой регулярке не экранированы символы [ и ].

В JavaScript все регулярные выражения, по умолчанию, жадные. То есть, стараются отхватить как можно больший кусок от строки. То есть, если вы ищете `/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/g` в строке "[b]текст[/b] текст [b]текст[/b]", то найдётся вся строка. Для подавления жадности регулярных выражений в JavaScript достаточно добавить `?` после `*` или `+`. То есть, не `(.*)`, а `(.*?)`.

Comment: Плюс, но можно было пару слов про жадность написать для топикстартера :)

Comment: @artuska, добавил. Сразу хотел написать, но как-то забыл.

Comment: Спасибо, знак вопроса оказался решением проблемы)